# Updating a Number Column with a string , so wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server

See the following sql statement, where I add a number column and populate it .

```
 ALTER TABLE #TMP_TABLE1 ADD [WEIGHT RECORDED] [decimal](18, 2) NULL


  UPDATE #TMP_TABLE1 
  SET [WEIGHT RECORDED] = [TOTAL WEIGHT] * ISnull( COALESCE ( [AI PERCENTAGE_RECYCLED] ,[OI PERCENTAGE_RECYCLED],[SMB PERCENTAGE_RECYCLED])/100, 0)
  FROM #TMP_TABLE1
```

Now I have a requirement where the percentage recycled does not exist in the 3 columns then to populate the contents of the `[WEIGHT RECORDED]` column with `N/A` for that record . However the `[WEIGHT RECORDED]` column is a number . How do I do this without changing the column definition and compromising the numbers held for other records which will be numbers ?

Comment: set it to null. display null as N/A.

Comment: To expand slightly on @dotjoe's point, how you store the data in the database and how you display the data in an application or report are two completely different things. Leave the value in database as `NULL` and just display it as 'N/A' when you query it.

Comment: How to display as 'N/A' When you query it . I get Error converting data type varchar to numeric Error ?

Comment: By the way `ISNULL` is superfluous in this example, ISNULL and COALESCE do the same thing, except that ISNULL takes exactly 2 terms.  Instead of `ISnull( COALESCE ( [AI PERCENTAGE_RECYCLED] ,[OI PERCENTAGE_RECYCLED],[SMB PERCENTAGE_RECYCLED])/100, 0)`, you could use `COALESCE ( [AI PERCENTAGE_RECYCLED] ,[OI PERCENTAGE_RECYCLED],[SMB PERCENTAGE_RECYCLED], 0)/100` (0/100 is still 0)

Comment: how to display as `'N/A'` in a query....`select isnull(cast([weight recorded] as varchar), 'N/A')` ...but it's better left to the reporting layer. There you can decide on the number format and what to display when it's null.